# Html navbar Overlapping body (Messing w/ my anchors)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using navbar-fixed-top (twitter bootstrap) in this website. I am wondering there is a way to make the bottom of the navbar act like the top of the browser.

See the issue is that I don't like the when the anchors change (to and from active). My navbar is overlapping my body and i don't want that to happen anywhere in the webpage... EVER!!

As you can see I have tried to add padding to the body but it just pushes the body down 50 px. Does anyone know a fix for this? I don't mind having to mess with Jquery

Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/xXDarksnakeXx/409tfas4/

A comment I made to pol:

"... I want the bottom of the navbar to act like the top of the browser this way when a div reaches the bottom of the navbar (instead of the top of the browser) then the anchors in the navbar will change to active."

```css
/* BOOTSTRAP 3.x GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}



/* NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar-default {
 background-color: #763f8d;
 border-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
 color: #ecdbff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
 color: #ecdbff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
 color: #ecdbff;
 background-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
 color: #ecdbff;
 background-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
 border-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
 background-color: #5e2d73;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
 border-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
 color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
 color: #ecdbff;
}

/* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
}


/* Jumbotron
-------------------------------------------------- */
.jumbotron {

}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Pad the edges of the mobile views a bit */
.marketing {
  padding-top: 75px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
}

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#team-btn {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}
.featurette {
  padding-top: 120px; /* Vertically center images part 1: add padding above and below text. */
  overflow: hidden; /* Vertically center images part 2: clear their floats. */
}
.featurette-image {
  margin-top: -120px; /* Vertically center images part 3: negative margin up the image the same amount of the padding to center it. */
}

/* Give some space on the sides of the floated elements so text doesn't run right into it. */
.featurette-image.pull-left {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
.featurette-image.pull-right {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}

    
    
/* Footer
-------------------------------------------------- */

hr { 
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
}

footer {
    
}


/* Responsive CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
    
/* Navigation */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
 }
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ecdbff;
  background-color: #5e2d73;
 }
}

/* Marketing */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .marketing {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 980px) {
    body {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="0" id="home">
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="0" id="home">
        <header>
          <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
              <div id="navtop" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The James Baldwin School</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#faculty">Faculty</a></li>
                        
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Parents <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
              
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Students <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Teachers <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                        </ul>
                    </div><!--- /.navbar-collapse collapse --->
                  
                    </div><!--- /#navtop --->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
            </div><!-- /.navbar wrapper -->
        </header>

<!--- JAMES-BALDWIN ========================================================
============================================================================ --->

        <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Baldwin" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1757925/thumbs/o-JAMES-BALDWIN-facebook.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
        <div class="image-caption">
        
        </div>

<!--- JUMBOTRON ============================================================
============================================================================ --->

        <div class="jumbotron" id="about">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="text-center">
                <h1>The James Baldwin School</h1>
                <h2>A School For Expeditionary Learning.</h2>
                <p>It is our mission to provide a philosophical and practical education for all students, an education that features creativity and inquiry, encourages habitual reading and productivity, as well as self-reflection and original thought.  We agree with Socrates that the “unexamined life is not worth living,” and it is our desire to prepare students to live thoughtful and meaningful lives. We are committed to inspiring the love of learning in our students.</p>
                <p>It is our mission, as well, at the James Baldwin School, to provide a haven for students who have previously experienced school as unresponsive to their needs as individuals.  We wish for all students to find their voice and to speak knowledgeably and thoughtfully on issues that concern their school, their world.  We aid students in this endeavor by personalizing our learning situations, by democratizing and humanizing the school environment, and by creating a “talking culture,” an atmosphere of informal intellectual discourse among students and faculty.</p>
                <p>Democratizing the school would be impossible without our Core Values. Our core values help students aquire the important skills needed to continue their journey through life. Most importantly, our core values maintain safety  and democracy for students and faculty.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="#">Learn more about Core Values</a>
              </div>    
          </div>        
        </div>        
        
<!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes ===================================
============================================================================ -->

        <div class="container marketing" id="faculty">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
              <h2>Brady Smith</h2>
              <p>Principal Co-Director</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
              <h2>Josh Heisler</h2>
              <p>Teacher Co-Director</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
              <h2>Christine Olsen</h2>
              <p>Admissions</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a></p>
            </div>
              
                        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
              <h2>Brady Smith</h2>
              <p>Principal Co-Director</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
              <h2>Josh Heisler</h2>
              <p>Teacher Co-Director</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a></p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
              <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/140x140">
              <h2>Christine Olsen</h2>
              <p>Admissions</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details</a></p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.row -->
  
        <div id="team-btn">
          <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-large btn-danger" href="#">See the rest of Our Team</a>
          </div><!--- /.text-center --->
        </div><!--- /.team-btn --->


  <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

    

  <!--- /END THE FEATURETTES --->

        </div><!-- /.container marketing -->
        
  <!-- FOOTER -->
        
        <hr>
        
        <div class="container">          
            <footer class="text-center" id="footer">
                <p>This site was created by Isaac Perez.<a href="#"> Back to top.</a></p>
                <p>Copyright 2014 &copy; The James Baldwin School. <br>Some Rights Reserved</p>
            </footer>
        </div><!-- /.container -->
        
<!--- Javascript Bootsrap --->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a class to the a tag which containing the image like that

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Baldwin" target="_blank" class="banner_image"><img     src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1757925/thumbs/o-JAMES-BALDWIN-facebook.jpg" style="width:100%"></a>
```

Now add this css rule to your css:

```
a.banner_image{
 display:block; 
 margin-top:50px; /* adjust the margin, what will be the height of the navbar */
}
```

Comment: Pol, I just apply this to my webpage; and it didnt solve the issue that I was having... a want the bottom of the navbar to act like the top of the browser this way when a div reaches the bottom of the navbar (instead of the top of the browser) then the anchors in the navbar will change to active.